# How to find max number of tasks that I can run using slurm?

Tags: slurm

I have access to supercomputer that uses slurm, but I need one information, that I cannot find. How many  parallel tasks can I run? I know I can use --ntasks to set the number, and e.g. if I have parallel prblen and I want to check it running 1000 processes I can run it with --ntasks 1000 but what sets max number? Nuber of nodes or number of CPUs or something else?

Answer (score 4):

There is a physical limitation which is the total number of cores available in the cluster. You can check that with `sinfo -o%C`; the last number in the output will be the total number of CPUs.

There can also be limits defined in the "Quality of Services". You can see them with `sacctmgr show qos`. Look for the `MaxTRES` column.

But there can be also administrative limits specific to your user or your account. You can see them with `sacctmgr show user $USER withassoc`. Look for the `MaxCPUMins` column.